# fuelphp - how can I add a custom path to the asset class?

Tags: php, class, url, fuelphp, assets

Ok,

So quick question that is driving me crazy with FuelPHP

For css, js, and img assets I can do this in a view

```
<?php echo Asset::css('main.css'); ?>
```

But if I try to add a folder - for example - "media" to the public/assets directory I can not do this:

```
<?php echo Asset::media('myvideo.mp4'); ?>
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to configure that kind of functionality? Has anyone been able to modify the asset class to do that?

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is such fashion that you could create your own static method name (the one you like is `media` as I haven't tried it yet). But you declare that path instead. Consider this example:

***(file is in `public/assets/media/file.mp4`)***

**Controller**

```
Asset::add_path('assets/media/', 'media');
```

**View**

```
<a href="<?php echo Asset::get_file('file.mp4', 'media'); ?>">Video 1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create such methods by extending the core class.

This can not be solved generically (for example with a magic __call()), because the class would not know which HTML to generate for "media" (or whatever you want to add).